# Installing Swift on Windows

Tags: swift, windows, visual-studio

I am following the steps in https://www.swift.org/getting-started/#on-windows

Everything is fine except the last step running the following in x86 Native Tools for VS2019 Command Prompt

```
copy /Y %SDKROOT%\usr\share\ucrt.modulemap "%UniversalCRTSdkDir%\Include\%UCRTVersion%\ucrt\module.modulemap"
copy /Y %SDKROOT%\usr\share\visualc.modulemap "%VCToolsInstallDir%\include\module.modulemap"
copy /Y %SDKROOT%\usr\share\visualc.apinotes "%VCToolsInstallDir%\include\visualc.apinotes"
copy /Y %SDKROOT%\usr\share\winsdk.modulemap "%UniversalCRTSdkDir%\Include\%UCRTVersion%\um\module.modulemap"
```

The 1st and 4th execute fine but with the 2nd and 3rd I get the error "System could not find the specified file"

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of swift are you installing?

Comment: A sorry if this seems obvious, but my guess is that the `VCToolsInstallDir` environment variable isn't set to the right directory.  I haven't used Swift on Windows, and my one attempt at building it a few years ago failed, but I would try adding `echo VCToolsInstallDir = %VCToolsInstallDir%` before you do the copy and see what it outputs, and manually check that location to see if the expected files are there.  Is it set?, Is it missing a drive specifier?  That's where I'd start.  Also check that `%SKDROOT\usr\share` contains `visualc.modulemap` and `visualc.apinotes`.

Comment: It appears %SDKROOT%\usr\share does contains neither visualc.modulemap or visualc.apinotes. The folders in the folder returned by echo VCToolsInstallDir = %VCToolsInstallDir% are Auxiliary, bin, crt, include and lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two failing file paths indicate that the file names start with “visualc”.  Those file names have been changed to start with “vcruntime”.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).