# Issues Installing Swift on Windows 10

Tags: swift, windows

I'm attempting to install & compile Swift programs with the Swift compiler on Windows 10.

I first downloaded & installed the Swift compiler for Windows from [the official Swift website](https://www.swift.org/download/). I have Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition, with the `Desktop development with C++` package installed.

I then followed [the official Windows tutorial on the Swift website](https://www.swift.org/install/windows/), and tried both the Windows Package Manager method and the Traditional method. In each case, I couldn't access any of the Swift commands in either the Visual Studio Native Command Prompt or the standard Windows Command Prompt. `swift` and `swiftc` are unrecognized commands.

Albeit, I did create an Environment Variable for `SDKROOT` with `C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows.platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk` (which does appear to contain the Swift libraries), yet it did not appear to fix the issue.

I also made sure that the `visualc.modulemap` and `visualc.apinotes` files that I was copying using the VS Native Command Prompt according to the tutorial had the correct naming of `vcruntime.modulemap` and `vcruntime.apinotes`, according to [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76193960/installing-swift-on-windows).

I then followed [the following tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKN60MoqGn8), where the instructee followed most of the same steps described in the Traditional method of the official Swift website tutorial, and attempted to compile a `swift` file to an executable. Yet, my `swift` and `swiftc` commands still remained unaccessible in any Command Prompt.

I then followed [the following tutorial](https://medium.com/@illescasDaniel/run-swift-on-windows-11-in-2021-675d703e7a91), where the instructee creates a makefile and attempts to build a `swift` file using that. However, attempting to run the `nmake build` command in a Command Prompt on a makefile called `build` simply resulted in the message `'build' is up-to-date`. I'm not familliar with the makefile program building methods, so I may very well be missing something here. The `swift` and `swiftc` commands remained unaccessible.

What is the proper way to install Swift on a Windows 10 system? Does Swift only work with Visual Studio 2019, and not 2022?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the directory containing the compiler to your path variable? Type `echo %PATH%` at a command prompt and see if the Swift executable directory is there

Comment: @JeremyP I do see a Swift path in that list, I see `C:\Program Files\Swift\runtime-development\usr\bin`. That folder appears to contain a variety of DLL files and a single executable called `plutil.exe`. Is that the executable you referenced? Or does an additional directory need to be included?

Comment: The directory containing `swift.exe` and `swiftc.exe` needs to be in your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it was finally solved. I completely reinstalled everything relating to Swift, but this time I followed [the following guide](https://github.com/pwsacademy/swift-setup/blob/main/platforms/windows/README.md), and installed the Swift toolchain via the Command Prompt instead of the installer from the website. I see now that there are also many more files in the Swift Libraries folder that previously weren't there, so something got messed up the first time... I'm finally able to access the Swift commands via the command prompt.

Regardless, that's a really good Swift installation guide for Windows and other systems.